# "There was no endpoint listening at..."

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I'm trying to run a simple WCF Service...

My Wcf Service .config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name ="WebService.Receptor">
    <endpoint
      address = "http://MyServer:8000/WS"
      binding = "wsHttpBinding"
      contract = "IMyContract"
    />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

My Windows Service .config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint 
    name = "Receptor"
    address = "http://MyServer:8000/WS"
    binding = "wsHttpBinding"
    contract = "IMyContract"
    />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Obs: The Wcf Service is running under IIS 7.5 on Windows 7.

So, when i try to call a method from the wcf proxy (IMyContract) i got this error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://MyServer:8000/WS that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The inner exception:

> {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you host a WCF service in IIS you don't specify an absolute url in the address. You should use a relative url to the `.svc` file. The base url will be determined by the web site where it is hosted.

```
<service name="WebService.Receptor">
    <endpoint
        address="/WS.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="IMyContract"
     />
</service>
```

and on the client, depending on how your IIS is configured you should obviously specify the full address:

```
<client>
    <endpoint 
        name="Receptor"
        address="http://MyServer:8000/WS.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="IMyContract"
    />
</client>
```

This assumes that you have configured a site in IIS that listens on the 8000 port and that you have hosted your WCF application inside this site.